# Google Ad Manager SDK fo IOS

Tags: ios, swift

I have an audio player. I integrated Google advertising into it. Everything works fine, but there is one point that I wanted to fix, how to make my ad duplicate on the View player and also on the footer while making only one request

I need to duplicate the same advertisement request on two different containers

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I need to duplicate the same advertisement request on two different containers